# array to exclude specific categories from showing as FIRST category using get_the_category()

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using this code to show **only the first category** of a post on my page template but I need to find a way to exclude some specific categories from it

```
$category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name;?
```

Example:

Let's say that I have a post on tree categories: **"admin cat"** and **"admin cat2"** and **"item cat"**. If I use this function, the output will be:

*This post is under **"admin cat"**!*

and I need it to be:

*This post is under **"item cat"**!*

Is it possible to add an array of cats that will be omitted on the output to my code or should I be using other method?

Comment: do you always want end of category it it may be random ??

Comment: @sismaster Can you explain your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-categories-from-the_category/

```
<?php the_excluded_category(array(1,328,338,339)); ?>
function the_excluded_category($excludedcats = array()){
$count = 0;
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $count++;
    if ( !in_array($category->cat_ID, $excludedcats) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "Cortos de %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';

        if( $count != count($categories) ){
            echo ", ";
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is meant to output ONLY the ONE category

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through your category array and match each item against an array of excluded categories. This will return the first non-matching category.

```
function getCategory() {
    $categories = array('admin cat','admin cat2', 'item cat', 'some other cat', 'dog');
    $excluded_categories = array('admin cat','admin cat2');

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if (!in_array($category,$excluded_categories)) {
            return $category;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo getCategory();
// outputs 'item cat'

?>
```